# Python mathplotlib - overlapping texts in xticks and adding percentage symbol in yticks

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

The following is my Python code for generating a bar chart:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.rcdefaults()
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

objects = ('Increasing operational efficiency',
       'Informing strategic direction',
       'Better customer service',
       'Identifying and developing new products',
       'Enhanced customer experience',
       'Identifying new markets',
       'Faster go to market',
       'Complying with regulations',
       'Other')
y_pos = np.arange(len(objects))
performance = [51, 36, 27, 24, 20, 11, 8, 6, 3]

plt.bar(y_pos, performance, align='center', alpha=0.5)
plt.xticks(y_pos, objects)

plt.show()
```

In the output the xticks are getting overlapped, is there any way to overcome it. My second doubt is in the yticks the values are coming from 0 to 60 with a interval of 10, is there any way to add a '%' symbol along with the number like 0%, 10%, ..., 60% rather than 0, 10, ..., 60.

Thank you for the help, I am new to mathplotlib

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you would have found answers to your questions with a simple search...

you can rotate the x-axis labels using `plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()`

for the percent signs on the y-axis, use

```
ax = plt.gca()
vals = ax.get_yticks()
ax.set_yticklabels(['{:.0f}%'.format(x) for x in vals])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Diziet, but few labels are not fitting inside the window. Is there any way to expand the window?

Comment: To automatically expand the window at the right size, you could use `plt.tight_layout()`